# Not able to load module in AngularJs, after deploying to server(GCP-AppEngine). Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a piece of code(abc.ts file), which is responsible for loading a HTML related content using $routeProvider and angular.module.
Respective file is loading properly in local machine, but in server its resulting in a error as stated below.

Note: we are using AngularJs with TypeScript and JavaScript combination, also using Closure. Eventually JS & closure usage is being removed.

abc.ts file:

```
import 'angular-route';
import * as angular from 'angular';
import {AbcLinkController} from './filepath';

/** @ngInject */
function configureRoutes($routeProvider: angular.route.IRouteProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('abcLink/:pathVariable1:pathVariable2', {
  templateUrl:'abclink/abc-file-name.ng',
  controller: AbcLinkController,
  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  });
}

export const module: angular.IModule = 
  angular.module('abc', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute'])
    .config(configureRoutes);
```

Sinppet from app.js file:

```
module =
    angular
        .module(
            'applicationName.app',
            [
              'ngMockE2E',
              'ngRoute',
              'ngSanitize',
              'angularMoment',
              abc.module.name,
...
```

Browser console error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4-local+sha.617b36117/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24routeParams%24%24Provider%20%3C-%20%24%24routeParams%24%24
    at js.js?437e15ca-1865-4083-a6cd-f574d2d2b01d:4107
    at js.js?437e15ca-1865-4083-a6cd-f574d2d2b01d:4142
    at Object.y [as get] (js.js?437e15ca-1865-4083-a6cd-f574d2d2b01d:4139)
    at js.js?437e15ca-1865-4083-a6cd-f574d2d2b01d:4142
    at y (js.js?437e15ca-1865-4083-a6cd-f574d2d2b01d:4139)
    at v (js.js?437e15ca-1865-4083-a6cd-f574d2d2b01d:4140)
    at Object.instantiate (js.js?437e15ca-1865-4083-a6cd-f574d2d2b01d:4140)
    at js.js?437e15ca-1865-4083-a6cd-f574d2d2b01d:4192
    at Object.link (js.js?437e15ca-1865-4083-a6cd-f574d2d2b01d:4509)
    at js.js?437e15ca-1865-4083-a6cd-f574d2d2b01d:4117 "<div ng-view=\"\" class=\"ng-scope\" data-ng-animate=\"1\">"
```

What could be wrong here?